# position two div having border inside a div

Tags: css, html, cross-browser

I have a outer div having two inner divs in that one div(leftDiv)
has a left-border of 1px this cause the right div to be moved out of the outerDiv.

**CSS**

```
.outerDiv{
    display: block;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFF;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 1%;     
    width: 97.5%;
    border: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 13px -2px #D6D6D6;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.leftDiv{
    height: 400px;
    width: 65%;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
}
.rightDiv{
    height: 400px;
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
    background:orange;      
}
```

**JSfiddle:**[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/267SR/)

I need the rightDiv to occupy the complete remaining space of outerDiv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin-left: -1px` to `.rightDiv`.

```
.rightDiv{
    height: 400px;
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
    background:orange;      
    margin-left:-1px;
}
```

I added `-1px` margin to `.rightDiv` to cutoff the border-right space of the `.leftDiv`. which is `1px`.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/267SR/4/)**

**OR**

Using `positioning` - [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/267SR/7/)

**OR**

Using `display: table-cell` - **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/267SR/8/)**

Comment: did & btw margin-left: -1px seems not a generic solution in terms of designing, the other two are better.

Comment: @Twocode I agree, the first one is not good if the container has text in it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions:

1. add margin-left:-1px; to .rightDiv - this is very cross-browser
   or
2. add box-sizing: border-box to .leftDiv - this is supported on IE8 and above + modern browsers

Answer (score 0):

you can use css3's calc property to deal with percentage and pixels both at a time..
use:

```
.leftDiv{
    height: 400px;
    width: calc(65% - 1px);
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
}
```

check this:  http://jsfiddle.net/267SR/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule

```
.outerDiv div {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/267SR/2/

`box-sizing: border-box;` will include the border size inside the width of the div elements

Answer (score 0):

Because `65% + 35% + 1px` is higher than `100%`, it shifts down.

Lower one of the percents by one and you have it working!

http://jsfiddle.net/267SR/3/

Answer (score 0):

use  `box-sizing: border-box`

```
 .leftDiv{
            height: 400px;
            width: 65%;
            float: left;
            border-right: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8N64s/)

Answer (score 0):

So many different answers here, all of which are good. I'm just posting this one just as another alternative, but maybe not necessarily the best option.

I added an `:after`, so no actual code was changed in the way it looked.

This way, you don't need to make anything bigger, or smaller. Just add something on top of the current `.leftDiv`.

Add

```
position:relative;
```

to `.leftDiv`'s css.

Then add this to the CSS:

```
.leftDiv:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:1px;
    background:#333;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A46kw/)

Answer (score 0):

See changes, make `display:inline` of the `divs` and `float` correctly.

All browsers friendly

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/267SR/9/)

Comment: A floating element doesn't obey `display` property and also still the border to the left element is not visible in your fiddle. :)

Comment: @Mr_Green would you take a screenshot shows the difference b/w yours and mine plz, the left border is there for sure. btw, floating doesn't but 'display:inline' lines up the two divs

Comment: Change the color to some darker color like `red` and check.